# How to get video tags from a Youtube video?

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I want to get the tags of a video from Youtube using the video's URL. I have searched in Google, but mostly I get the answer that "YouTube's API can no longer be used to retrieve tags".

Is there still a way that I can get video tags from a YouTube video using PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example for URL : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LIjs3-8cZVA

```
$connect = file_get_contents("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LIjs3-8cZVA");
preg_match_all('|<meta property="og\:video\:tag" content="(.+?)">|si', $connect, $tags, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    echo $tag[1] . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try

```
$meta = get_meta_tags( "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LIjs3-8cZVA" );
$tags = isset( $meta['keywords'] ) ? $meta['keywords'] : '';
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your question to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use videos.list API method for tags, instead of downloading the whole content.

Here's a PHP sample: https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/php/update_video.php#L73

Comment: Using the YouTube API (v3), you don't have access to video tags unless the video belongs to the authenticated user. Hope it helps.